# Como pegar e exibir dados de checkbox desselecionado PHP

Tags: php, html, checkbox, foreach

Tenho uma tabela onde uma coluna é composta por checkbox. No futuro, os status desses checks serão salvos em um banco de dados para carregamento automático, mas no momento, para fins de teste e também de facilitação do entendimento da pergunta, preciso apenas mostrar o status desse check e o seu valor.
Esse é meu código PHP até o momento:

```
<?php

// Verifica se usuário escolheu algum check
if(isset($_POST["nome"]) {
    echo "Os checks que você escolheu são: ";

    // Faz loop pelo array do check
    foreach ($_POST["nome"] as $check) {
        //pega o status do checkbox
        $_POST["nome"] = isset($_POST["nome"]) ? "checked" : null;
        $valor = $_POST["nome"];

        echo "$valor $check";
    }
}
```

Quando vou SELECIONAR um check ele mostra certinho:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Contudo, ao DESSELECIONAR não aparece nada. Não entendo muito de PHP, mas imagino que é como se eu não tivesse selecionado nada. Preciso de uma solução o quanto antes.

P.S: Na tabela há um form action comum direcionando para a página PHP e dentro um `input type:checkbox` com `onchange="this.form.submit()"`.

Comment: O HTML não envia `checkbox` não selecionados. Além disso, o código dentro do `foreach` não faz sentido, você está validando `isset($_POST['nome'])`, quando que, para estar dentro do `foreach`, o valor já deve ter sido definido. Qual é a sua real intenção, é bem provável que outra solução seja adequada ao seu problema?

Comment: A menos que você envie o valor 'S' ou 'N' para o post ai sim você poderá tratar